# How can I fix Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 X64 Minimum Runtime error during installing Redistributable packages (VC_redist.x64.exe, VC_redist.x86.exe)?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer, vcredist

During installation I get "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable" and prompt to specify some path to vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi. After providing some path to required file I get error states that this file doesn't match required version Minimum Runtime 14.14.26405.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution reading this question: [Install vcredist_x64 with VS2017 installer project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032469/install-vcredist-x64-with-vs2017-installer-project)

I realized that specific VC_Redist.x64.exe files could be downloaded by links like https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/26405.00/VC_Redist.x64.exe, where `26405.00` is exactly the version I was required to fix. Note, that you need version from error text after clicking OK, not from window title.

And the last point is that this exe must be executed from cmd with argument `/repair` to help me with this issue. Regular execution by double click made no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution elsewhere. It said to
Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed
download troubleshooter button on the link.
Run it - choose option - have problem with installing - it lists programs - choose the missing / problematic visual c++ runtimes in the list
it will run and get fixed.
Repeat for each visual c++ you having problems with. I ran the program multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

I have to thank this comment section for helping me with this problem, since I have not been able to work more efficently with my school, since I din't know what and if a single file somewhere deep down in the computer had to be deleted for this program to work.

Comment: The message is nice. But doesn't respect the content rules of Stack Overflow.